# Laravel Passport (auth code grant with PKCE) + NuxtJS SPA + CSRF token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, nuxt.js, csrf

I looked through different posts already and I didn't see anything that would answer my questions so...

I am building an app that has a separate SPA built with NuxtJS. There's also a Laravel 8 backend serving as an API.

Laravel passport is used for auth. However, I realized that I used password auth grant where I should've used auth code grant with PKCE. So now I am rewriting it.

The problem I encountered is as follows:

So imagine that the user clicks the login button. For the code auth grant, I need to redirect to the web route of my API that would hold the login form. However I do not want to do it like that, I want to stay in my SPA and use the login form there.

In order to do that I need to get the CSRF token **safely** to the frontend. As you know Laravel will require that. I don't want to turn it off. I think it should be there, at all times. Now I am not sure how to exactly do that.

To my understanding, I can use an encrypted cookie from which my SPA could get the CSRF token and send it to the web login endpoint. I know that Laravel sanctum has an endpoint that issues the cookie (but remember I am using passport).

Now I am mostly interested in understanding if I am right about this.

Is it ok to do something like that:

- user clicks login button which calls backend endpoint to set an encrypted CSRF cookie
- after the cookie is set, SPA automatically shows login form
- user enters credentials and sends them along with CSRF token
- token should only be accepted if it comes from my SPA domain

Does it make sense and does it seem right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to do is very insecure, and it is [the reason why](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4) the password grant is removed. Simply put, you `expose the credentials of the resource owner to the client`.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I don't think you understood my question. This is exactly what I am saying. The app is still in dev and I realized I used the wrong grant. I want to replace the password grant with the authorization code grant. The question is about authorization code grant not password one.

Comment: You say you want to bring the login form to your SPA application (client)? So what you want to do, is to use the PKCE grant but change the flow to be insecure like the password grant. In short, you **must login at the authorization server**.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden ah now when you say it like that it makes sense. I see what you mean now. You're right, my bad. I thought you think I am trying to use password grant. Hmm is there anything to make the user experience better? I will put that page in there in the auth server, for sure. I was thinking I will just open the URL from auth server in new small window inside of the SPA dialog window so it will pretend to be native to SPA. Is that acceptable? What do you think?

Comment: At first, this indeed feels strange when you only have a single client. But do notice, that a user needs to be able to register, login, forget password, change credentials and maybe setup 2fa or verify their email. You could display a view based on the `client_id`.

Comment: [1/3] - I had the same problem, Laravel 8 and Nuxt.JS. Using [nuxtjs/auth][1] package with [Laravel Sanctum][2] does work without any redirects and the user remains on the SPA. However this wasn't the solution I was looking for in my case I have auth service just deals with the authentication and authorisation for multiple applications. If Laravel sanctum doesn't do the job for you. You may want to go with your own api authentication route. I do understand security comes first. So you can always protect your own api authentication endpoint for brute force and etc.

Comment: [2/3]  You can introduce your own authentication route (where you can accept email/username and password if user is valid you can generate access token and return. Once you have the access token you can still use the nuxtjs/auth package to set access token. What about user details? You can add another endpoint /api/user to return user details and related permissions and roles you would need for your application. nuxtjs/auth handles this for you already you just need to set the URL.

Comment: [3/3] You may also want to consider:
 - User password reset, as you want the user to remain on spa you probably want to keep the user on SPA for password reset. And when the email is sent you want SPA url to appear instead of your API.
 - What about user permissions and roles.
 - [API Rate limit][3]


  [1]: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/
  [2]: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum
  [3]: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden, yep I think I understand. So the client means the DB row I generate with passport for auth code grant, this will have its own id of course, and based on that I can display different things. Do I actually have to redirect the user or can I just load it up in a separate window? Am I getting that right? I'll check out jetstream.

Comment: You can always introduce your own guard to handle things. Incase you need to introduce API Keys etc.. in the future. There are just so many cases. I hope above helps.

Comment: Yes, the `client_id` is for every SPA application (client) unique. So you can display a view based on `$request->get('client_id');` or some config wrapping. The `/oauth/authorize` url will stay the same, only display another view.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas thanks for so elaborate response! I wanna use passport because I will use API in more apps in the future, plus I wanna learn about it. Now I have password grant but behind my own API endpoint in which I make subrequest with credentials just like you described. But because my app is not live yet I don't wanna leave such a tech debt in there as this is strongly discouraged. I also use nuxt auth and have the config for getting user and middleware to check roles and things. A lot of great ideas you have!

Comment: I have an authorization server running with [Jetstream](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/introduction.html). Removed the API feature and added Passport. This adds login, registration, email verification, two-factor authentication, session management and optional team management features. I also added OpenID Connect, but that is just an add-on.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden sounds really good, I will defo check it out. I am not sure yet if I add it, I am trying to do MVP get it live, and then add more stuff. But I gotta say that sounds like something I will want to do in the future. Most of that I think.

Comment: [1/2] if you are planning to allow external or other internal services to use same API, i would be careful with Laravel Passport. Laravel Passport uses OAuth2, which requests more than one transaction (requests to validate the user). 

I went with the sanctum solution to solve authentication and introduced private and public keys like Stripe on top of it. This way I can make sure that my auth service is aware of the applications/services that can make request to my application and separate SPA from backend services. Because I can add more rules to check when authorising other services.

Comment: [2/2] For example you want to be able to track where your users are trying to login in and do they have permission for that application. 

I prefer to have public API key for every single SPA this way I can keep track of the permissions per user for each application and keep logs of their activities. 

This way you don't need to pass client_id. By the way jetstream uses sanctum too.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas yeah I just realised that Jetstream uses sanctum, just had a read about it :D Eh, this sanctum is following me everywhere I go. I may have explained things incorrectly. I intend to use the API in different project but it will be separate instance, completely unrelated. This API I am building serves two purposes. I learn a lot while building it and it is a foundation for future projects. I will just get it  from github for next project and build on top of that. Does that make sense? I know I can make things confusing sometimes.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas currently I am building an app that will use the first version of my API, that is why I wanna do just basic but solid work on it. Trying to avoid rabbit holes. I always loose track of time!

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas Sanctum does not support single sign-on (SSO). It combines authorization server with resource server.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yes I agree, it doesn't support single sign on but its very simple to implement. With SSO the concern is after the user is authenticated. Again very simple just need a SSO data model with 64-128 hashed character assigned to user. 

it shouldn't be an issue to passing around the hashed sso token to trusted platforms. Once authorised the token should be destroyed and access token should be generated.